# JQuery function still working after removeing the class

Tags: jquery

I add and remove classes dynamicaly. But when I remove class the event still working. How to stop event to work.

```
$('.input').on('paste keypress, keydown', function(event) {
         fff();
})
```

But as soon as I add the class I need it to work.

Comment: check if the element has the class within the function before deciding to execute it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use event delegation and bind event with static parent.

```
$('.static-parent-class').on('paste keypress, keydown', '.input',  function(event) {
    fff();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you can not add a static class to parent you can remove the assigned events after removing the class like below

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4018wLf1/),

javascript

```
function fff() {
  alert('chacha!!');
}
$(function() {
  $('#removeClass').on('click', function() {
    $('.input').removeClass('input').off('paste keypress, keydown');
  });
  $('.input').on('paste keypress, keydown', function(event) {
    fff();
  })
});
```

Hope it works for you